# How to select a drop down option which exist in span tag using selenium webdrive java?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The dropdown main has ID in both DIV and IMG tags, I am able to click on the dropdown main using either one of these, however, I am not able to click on the dropdown options, please help.

**Source code of dropdown main:**

```
<div id="drop_mainmenu" tabindex="0">Navigator

<img id="mainmenu_downarrow" border="0" class="ArrowImg" alt="" title="" src="/jde/share/images/menu_l23_button_dropdown_dwn.png" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/share/images/menu_l23_button_dropdown_ovr.png'" onmousedown="this.src='/jde/share/images/menu_l23_button_dropdown_dwn.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/share/images/menu_l23_button_dropdown_dwn.png'" data-pin-nopin="true"><br>
</div>
```

**Source code of one of dropdown option:**

```
<span id="fldnode140398" style="color: #000000;font-style: normal;" title="Task Type:Task View, Fastpath Code: TV:140">Christie's Dubai</span>
```

Comment: Why do you `not able to click` it? Share your code

Comment: Here is my code, driver.findElement(By.id("mainmenu_downarrow")).click();              Select mainmenu_downarrow = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mainmenu_downarrow")));
    mainmenu_downarrow.selectByVisibleText("Christie's Dubai");

Comment: Select won't work I guess as there is now select written under html code.

Comment: @Jagadeesh Did you try my edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put some `wait` and try:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("mainmenu_downarrow")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Christie's Dubai')]")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.id("mainmenu_downarrow")).click();  
Thread.sleep(3000L); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(@id, 'fldnode140398')]")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.id("mainmenu_downarrow")).click();  
Thread.sleep(3000L); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[starts-with(@id, 'fldnode')]")).click();
```

Comment: Your xpath will not work here.. selenium doesn't recognize `'s`

Comment: Here is what I tried with your code, but its not working. driver.findElement(By.id("mainmenu_downarrow")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Christie's Dubai']")).click();